# Application().connect is not getting connected to 'Services' window

Tags: automation, desktop, pywinauto

Trying to open Start->Services window and connect `pywinAuto` Application to Services window using the title 'Services', But the application is not connecting to above mentioned window. The code written to open a Services window and connect with it is as mentioned below:

```
def search_webroot_in_services():
    childWindowFile='C:\Girish\DnsAutomation\childWindow.txt'
    try:
        #--------------------------
        desktop = Desktop(backend='uia')

        # click to open 'start' menu
        desktop.Pane.Start.click_input()
        desktop.StartMenu.child_window(auto_id="SearchTextBox", control_type="Edit").type_keys('services')
        keyboard.send_keys('{ENTER}')
    #Below line of code is not working
        app=Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Services',timeout=10)
        app.Services.print_control_identifiers()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error searching in Services Programs: {str(e)}")
        return False
```

Would like to connect to Services app, and check if the required services is running is the purpose of writing above code. The image of the Services window being tried to automate is attached.

Tried connecting the Services window using below code, but its not working.

```
app=Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Services',timeout=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Most probably "Services" window is implicitly started as Administrator (some system apps don't ask UAC confirmation) and you must run your script (or IDE or `python.exe`) as Administrator too (by right click menu item or by setting a shortcut `.lnk` file properties to always run as Administrator).

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov thanks for your response, I did try running the script with admin privileges and script went running for longer time and finally execution failed with following error: python UiElementInspect.py
Error searching in Add/Remove Programs: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Comment: You need to understand which method failed using full traceback and maybe use `.click_input()` instead of `.click()` since some apps don't implement some handlers properly. If you found the full solution for your problem, please post it as an answer and accept (by left side check box). It is OK to accept own answers. It will indicate to others that help is not needed any more.